# use existing MySQL Database in Laravel 4

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, database-migration

I'm a beginner in Laravel framework. I had created a MySQL Db using `phpmyadmin` designer wherein I could easily do relations between foreign keys etc etc. 
But Laravel 4 demands using `artisan` to create migrations and tables. I feel it'll be tedious to replicate the whole DB using commands and writing everything manually. 
My question here is:

Is it possible to use the existing MySQL database and generate migrations using it, so that, it will replicate all the relations and foreign keys and everything as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `artisan`and [Schema builder](http://laravel.com/docs/schema) is optional when creating your Laravel table structure and data seeding. Nothing prevents you from creating structure and data with the help of `phpmyadmin` or `mysqlimport`, and plugging your Laravel application directly into that database. Laravel will not know how the database structure and data were created, or if any [migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations) exist.

You could even mix these two approaches: create some structures via migrations and some via `phpmyadmin`. Bear in mind that version control would, however, be much easier if you stick to a single method.

Regarding the last part of your question: at least I am not aware of any tool that would convert your current database structure and data into Laravel migration + schema builder code. Such a tool would be handy and probably within reasonable amount of work to create.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If thats so, i'd prefer to use only `phpmyadmin` creating and editing database.Also, I do not require any version control for database (for now atleast). most tutorials/articles stress on migrations,schema builder present in Laravel which made me think that its compulsory to have them.

Comment: If you are developing by yourself (not in a team), you will be just fine with `phpmyadmin`, plus you can move to `artisan` migrations anytime later. It is very true that that even Laravel documentation does not really advertise the benefits or even the possibility of creating and maintaining database structure outside Laravel.

Comment: yeah, I'm doing it by myself. Thanks for the answer.